# create PhoneGap build on local system for multi-platform without uploading to GIT

Tags: cordova, build, local

I am looking for alternative to PhoneGap build https://build.phonegap.com/. I want to build locally on my pc without uploading to GIT.

I know I have to install Android, Windows, Blackberry OS on my Windows and I need to have Apple to build for IOS but If you know exact steps how to accomplish that please let me know.

Thanking in anticipation.

**Update:**

I have found a Wiki Page but running commands gave me an error "An error has occured"
[CommandLineToolingDesign](http://wiki.apache.org/cordova/CommandLineToolingDesign)

[cordova](https://npmjs.org/package/cordova)

I have installed Node JS and cordova. Now cordova build thworing me this error 
Image also attached

An error occurred while building project. { 
annot find the path specified. 
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null } 
The system cannot find the path specified.

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method I ended up using was this maven plugin:
http://chrisprice.github.com/phonegap-build/phonegap-build-maven-plugin/index.html

It's not a "local build" per se but it does get rid of the need to commit / push code before trying a build.

Basically you build a package locally and then the plugin ships the package over to phonegap-build.  Then it waits for the build to complete, retrieves the artifacts and reports the build results.  The whole process usually takes less than a minute for a normal sized app.